# How can I serve remote React app with a script tag?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, webpack

We have at our company a react app (built with create-react-app) which is served today via an iframe, which works well.

A need has risen to serve the app (which is always embedded within other pages), with a script tag alone (no iframe tag).

I thought of something like:

```
<div id="app-placeholder"></div>
<script src="https://our-app.com/init.js"></script> // this will create a function called window.InitMyApp
<script>
    InitMyApp('#app-placeholder', 'token', otherOptions)
</script>
```

I've tried to create `init.js` file in the react app's public folder. I can access the file.
From that file, how can I render the react app itself to the given selector (#app-placeholder)?

Because this file is served as-is, and doesn't get transpiled by webpack/babel, I cannot use import/jsx/require() and other stuff.

Am i on the right track?
Should I manually transpile this file?
Are there any other solutions to this rendering method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try configuring the compiler with [`{ output.library }`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-library). This should produce a compilation output that's ready for distribution, which means you can easily reference it in another document (and not need to worry about, say,  transpiling/optimizing sources, because this was already performed by webpack).

Here's an example of a [multi-part library](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/multi-part-library) produced by webpack. As you can see, the entrypoint exports are being assigned to `window`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this seems to be the right solution.
Now i'm getting an issue where Webpack tries to load a chunk file using the url of the hosting app, and obviously gets 404. any ideas how to tackle that?

Comment: @IdanPtichi providing the full URL via [`publicPath`](https://webpack.js.org/guides/public-path/) would probably be a good start.